# In C what is the fastest method of jumping to a function from a user specified input string

Tags: c, function, pointers, input

I am taking a user input from a serial interface where they can write commands with arguments. I would like to know what is the fastest method for jumping to a function from this input.

I have seen this done but cannot remember how it was implemented. I believe it used a table of strings each with an associated function pointer. Instead of using strcmp for each item in the table for matching strings, is there a way I can "drop in" to an element in that table from this string input?

Comment: Hashing and hash-tables? On average should be faster than calling `strcmp` in a loop, if the table is sufficiently large. If there are only a few entries then a loop and `strcmp` should be "good enough" (don't dismiss "good enough", especially before you measure!)

Comment: Maybe easier to think of it as how do i map a user input string of finite length to an array index.

Comment: Also, you can sort the table alphabetically and use binary search - available in posix with `bsearch` - this is almost as good as using a hashtable.

Comment: @RMS this is what hashing is about. However, a general hashing mechanism will have collisions, so you'd need to build a proper hashtable, not just use a bare hash, otherwise a typo like `cretae` could become a synonym for `self-destruct` :D

Comment: Remember: `bsearch` is standard C, not just POSIX.

Comment: A [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) might be faster. Attach your function pointers to nodes that correspond to valid keywords.

Comment: 'I am taking a user input from a serial interface' - does it matter how fast you jump to command handlers?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a prime material for XMacros in my opinion:
http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-x-macros/184401387

For example, define your table as:

```
#define COMMAND_FUNCTION_TBL \
#define _X(CMD_C, "copy", command_copy_handler)
#define _X(CMD_E, "exit", command_exit_handler)
...
#endif

// Enum
typedef enum {
#define _X(a,b,c) a,
COMMAND_FUNCTION_TBL
#undef _X
CMD_MAX
} CMD_ENUM_TYPE;


// String table
char command_string[CMD_MAX][] = { \
#define _X(a,b,c) b,
COMMAND_FUNCTION_TBL
#undef _X
}

// Function table
FUNC_PTR_TYPE command_function[CMD_MAX] = { \
#define _X(a,b,c) c,
COMMAND_FUNCTION_TBL
#undef _X
}
```

This portion of code handles the database of your commands to enum to function conversions, and in order to do the actual conversion you can do something as follows:

```
void command_dispatcher(char *command) {
   CMD_ENUM_TYPE i = 0;
   for (; i < CMD_MAX ; i++) {
        if (strcmp(command, command_string[i]) == 0) {
            command_function[i]();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a neat trick. But probably not the *fastest* method, especially if `CMD_MAX` is large.

Comment: Agreed, one possible solution would be implementing an hash-map of char[] key and CMD_ENUM_TYPE value and skip the searching through the array in a log(n) complexity. and then just accessing the function array on the produced hash-map value.

Comment: Also, just read your suggestion regarding a trie data structure - that might work pretty good here too.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on commands you are planning to use data type can be just `char` or string (`char *`).

So, for `char` you can use `switch` or operators `==` and `!=`, but for string it is better to use `strcmp` or `strncmp`

For example, command is one char with math operator:

```
char command;
int a1;
int a2;
int res;
printf("Entar a command for calcualation: ");
scanf("%d %c %d", &a1, &command, &a2);
switch (command)
{
case '+': res = a1 + a2;  // or res = add(a1, a2);
    break;
case '-': res = a1 - a2;
    break;
case '*': res = a1 * a2;
    break;
default: res = 0;
}
printf("Result is %d\n", res);
```

And if working with strings, the simplest way for comparison can be like:

```
// list of commands where last item is empty string
char commands[][20] = {"copy", "del", "compare", "clear",""};
char command[20];
char arg1[20];
char arg2[20];
printf("> ");
scanf("%s", command);
int commandID = 0;
// find what command was entered
while (commands[commandID][0] != '\0')
{
    if (!strcmp(commands[commandID], command))
        break; // stop the loop if command found
    commandID++;
}
if (commands[commandID][0] != '\0')
    printf("command ID is %d\n", commandID);
else
    printf("command is invalid\n");
```

Actually you can define ID for commands and strings with commands like enum and array of strings where ID is number in the array:

```
enum COM_ID{C_COPY, C_DEL, C_COMPARE, C_CLEAR, C_ERR};
char commands[][20] = {"copy", "del", "compare", "clear",""};
```

so, after `commandID` has a value `switch` can be used, e.g.:

```
switch (commandID)
{
case C_COPY: 
    ask2args(arg1, arg2); // your implementation to read 2 strings from stdin 
    copy(arg1, arg2); // your implementation of copy command
    break;
case C_DEL:
    ask1arg(arg1);
    del(arg1);
    break;
case C_COMPARE:
    ask2args(arg1, arg2);
    compare(arg1, arg2);
    break;
case C_CLEAR:
    clear();
    break;
}
```

Of course, the way you get the arguments can be different and depends on what kind of command and arguments you use. But the idea of conversion the command to integer number is like that, then you can use this ID as an index in the array of pointers to functions or in any other way you need.

For example, if you have

```
void(*fucs[4]) (const char * a1, const char * a2);
```

just call

```
fucs[commandID](arg1, arg2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hashing algorithms](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html) to create hashes from command strings you receive from serial interface.

The advantage of calculating hashes over compare strings is that you need to iterate through a string only once instead of the number of possible matches. If you precalculate hashes for every command, you can gain more speed.

In the following example I used the *LoseLose algorithm* (`hash = hash + character`) which is a **terrible** hashing algorithm but simple enough for an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void open() { puts("You choosed 'open'."); }
void copy() { puts("You choosed 'copy'."); }
void paste() { puts("You choosed 'paste'."); }

#define JUMP_TABLE \
    X(open, 'o' + 'p' + 'e' + 'n') \
    X(copy, 'c' + 'o' + 'p' + 'y') \
    X(paste, 'p' + 'a' + 's' + 't' + 'e')

int hash(const char *str) {
    int hash = 0, c;
    while(c = *str++) hash += c;
    return hash;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc < 2) {
        puts("Enter one of the following commands: 'open', 'copy' or 'paste'");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    switch(hash(argv[1])) {
#define X(func, hash) case hash: func(); break;
    JUMP_TABLE
#undef X
    default: puts("Unknown command.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the example above I used [X Macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) as well, to simplify the later maintenance of the code. You can use an `enum` too with hardcoded values.